# Impala DML operations in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, impala, processor

Is it possible to do impala DML operations within NiFi?

I have set up a DBCPConnectionPool that connects to impala and I can do select statements fine with the ExecuteSQL processor.

Now I'm wondering how (if possible) to do the DDL statement of

> `Alter Table "X" recover partitions;`

within Apache NiFi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do DML/DDL statements using the [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html) processor. ExecuteSQL is for statements/queries that return result set(s), PutSQL is for statements (INSERT, DML, DDL) that do not return result sets.